# Places Autocomplete API to get GPS coordinates from address entered

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I have an address field in my app where the user needs to enter the required address. I have used google Geocoder to get the GPS coordinates of the address . But now I want to make it easier for the user by using Places Autocomplete . But Places Autocomplete only returns the address , Id  and reference of the place .

Is there a way to get the GPS coordinates of the address selected by the user using Places Autocomplete API ? Do I have to use Geocoder again after the user selects his address from Places Autocomplete ?

Or Should I use Places API again after the user selects his address to get the GPS coordinates of the address ? I dont want to send multiple requests to the Places API because of the usage limits in place . . This is the expected response from Places API ..There is no GPS coordinates in the response .

```
"status": "OK",
  "predictions": [ {
    "description": "Paris, France",
    "id" : "691b237b0322f28988f3ce03e321ff72a12167fd",
    "reference": "CiQYAAAA0Q_JA...kT3ufVLDDvTQsOwZ_tc",
    "terms": [ {
      "value": "Paris",
      "offset": 0
    }, {
      "value": "France",
      "offset": 7
    } ],
    "types": [ "geocode" ],
    "matched_substrings": [ {
      "offset": 0,
      "length": 5
    } ]
  }, {
    "description": "Paris, TX, United States",
    "id" : "518e47f3d7f39277eb3bc895cb84419c2b43b5ac",
    "reference": "CjQjAAAAHnbxZZ...BDR3iIOFdMTxwo1jHg",
    "terms": [ {
      "value": "Paris",
      "offset": 0
    }, {
      "value": "TX",
      "offset": 7
    }, {
      "value": "United States",
      "offset": 11
    } ],
    "types": [ "geocode" ],
    "matched_substrings": [ {
      "offset": 0,
      "length": 5
    } ]
  }, {
    "description": "Paris, Ontario, Canada",
    "id" : "e7ac9c89d4a590305242b0cb5bf43064027223c9",
    "reference": "CjQhAAAAIv_YWYt...F8KZHY36TwMrbyu_g",
    "terms": [ {
      "value": "Paris",
      "offset": 0
    }, {
      "value": "Ontario",
      "offset": 7
    }, {
      "value": "Canada",
      "offset": 16
    } ],
    "types": [ "geocode" ],
    "matched_substrings": [ {
      "offset": 0,
      "length": 5
    } ]
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You simply use the [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details) part of the Places API where you get the actual place from the reference in each suggestion using the "reference" value. For example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CiQYAAAA0Q_JA...kT3ufVLDDvTQsOwZ_tc&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

This will give you information about the place including its coordinates (point for a specific location, bounds for an area).

Comment: If you want direct JavaScript access, you can also use the PlacesService from the Maps API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlacesService

Comment: use place_id instead of reference key... eg: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
  Ref link: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Comment: use 'placeid', not 'place_id' as stated by @xydev

Comment: what about the quotas limit?